# MvvmCross binding same ViewModel to both MT.Dialog RootElement (iOS) and MvxSpinner (Android)

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross, monotouch.dialog

Using MvvmCross, I have a ViewModel with a property that I want to bind in both iOS and Android. The property represents the item a user has selected from a list of items.

In iOS I have implemented the list using an MT.Dialog `RootElement` with `RadioElements`, binding to the `RadioSelected` property of the `RootElement` (similar to the example in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/DialogExamples/DialogExamples.Touch/Views/FirstView.cs):

```
new Section("Radio") {
    new RootElement("Dessert", new RadioGroup("Dessert", 0)) {
        new Section {
            radioChoices
        }
    }.Bind(bindings, e => e.RadioSelected, vm => vm.CurrentDessertIndex) as Element
}
```

where `CurrentDessertIndex` represents the index (which is an **int**) of the item selected.

In Android I am using an `MvxSpinner` for the list:

```
<MvxSpinner
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/itemspinner"
    local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/itemspinnerdropdown"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource radioChoices; SelectedItem CurrentDessert" />
```

Note that the `MvxSpinner` needs to bind to an **object** (and not an int).

This means I have to have two properties in my ViewModel representing the same thing, depending on the platform:

```
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private int _currentDessertIndex;
    public int CurrentDessertIndex 
    {   
        get { return _currentDessertIndex; }
        set { 
            _currentDessertIndex = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentDessertIndex); 
        }
    }

    private int _currentDessert;
    public int CurrentDessert 
    {   
        get { return _currentDessert; }
        set { 
            _currentDessert = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentDessert); 
        }
    }
}
```

How can I consolidate this to use only one property?

Comment: Upvoted this cause I'm also curious. All my solutions at the moment work with two separate properties like you described, one for index (iOS) and one for the object (Android). Anyway at that point I didn't feel it was so important to consolidate them to use only one property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be to link the two properties using RaisePropertyChanged - e.g.

```
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private int _currentDessertIndex;
    public int CurrentDessertIndex 
    {   
        get { return _currentDessertIndex; }
        set { 
            _currentDessertIndex = value; 
            _currentDessert = _desserts[value]; 
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentDessertIndex); 
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentDessert); 
        }
    }

    private Dessert _currentDessert;
    public Dessert CurrentDessert 
    {   
        get { return _currentDessert; }
        set { 
            _currentDessert = value; 
            _currentDessertIndex = _desserts.IndexOf(_currentDessert);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentDessertIndex); 
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentDessert); 
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it would be fairly straight-forward to add a custom binding to Android to support the index position in your project. You'd need to base this code on https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.2/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target/MvxSpinnerSelectedItemBinding.cs - but use the integer selection position rather than the selected object itself. See the N+1 on custom bindings in http://mvvmcross.blogger.com

Comment: Thanks @Stuart. I ended up going with creating a custom binding for the Android spinner to use an index.